# How to do an atomic update and select query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three columns - id , name and num. I want to select id based on name if num is larger than 0 and decrement num in the same sql statement - how can I do it? I need to make sure somehow that these 2 statements :

```
select id from table where name='someValue' ; update table set num=num-1;
```

would execute as atomic actions. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table set num=num-1 where name='somevalue' and num>0
```

This query will decrease num by 1 if num is greater than 0 and name is equal to 'somevalue'